# C# serialization class

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I have my class, example:

```
[Serializable]
public class ServerItem
{
    public string Id { get; }

    public string Name => this.info.Name;

    public bool IsOptimal { get; set; }

    public string Region => this.info.Region;

    public string City => this.info.Description;

    public Point? Location { get; }
}
```

I use my own method for serialize this class

```
public static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return bytes;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and I get the exception. That point cannot be serialized, because it hasn't attribute [Serializable]
But I can't set this attribute, because it's not my own class.
What can I do at this situation ?

Comment: I would highly recommend against using binaryformatter, it is considered completely obsolete by this points. There are much better alternatives, like xml, json or Protobuf.net.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you write a complilable repro?

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't helpful for you current problem, but Microsoft recommends strongly to don't use `BinaryFormatter` anymore.

> The ***`BinaryFormatter`*** type is dangerous and is ***not*** recommended for data
> processing. Applications should stop using `BinaryFormatter` as soon as
> possible, even if they believe the data they're processing to be
> trustworthy. `BinaryFormatter` is insecure and can't be made secure.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide

On this page are also further resources for alternatives.